# Find all Records that do not have a Foreign letter in a Sql Table

Tags: sql-server

I have been looking and doing research, and I am having trouble trying to split a table to two files, where one file only have English letters and special characters (such as `,.& () 0-9` - etc) and a second file that has all the records that have a foreign letter.

I have tried veriations of

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column_name like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

but that would not get special characters

also

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column_name like '%[\040-\176]%'
```

The data looks like this (not actual Data)

```
Doha, The Black Pearl
Jefferson City & Wells
Wenston 89-100
St. Winchester (T)
Piñata Valley
Not süre how to Üse that U
```

I have 4000 records and want to quickly look through the table. I want all the records but the last two.

Comment: Which database are you using? You have both mysql and sql server tagged.

Comment: I am using Sql Server

Comment: fix your tags please

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [REGEXP or RLIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp), not LIKE.